# Silverlight 'user initiated' security feature explained

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When programming for the Silverlight platform, I've found that I can't call two functions needing user initiation in the same user initiated event, one right after the other.

For example, suppose I want to call IsolatedStorage.IncreaseQuotaTo and SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog in the same button click event.  I can't because if the IncreaseQuotaTo call is made then the showdialog (or openfile) call throws a 'Must be user initiateted' exception.  The problem is that it is user initiated, except that it has a call to a user initiated function before it.

In a user initiated event, I should be able to call as many of these 'user initiated only' functions as I want, however, I am limited to only one.  It seems that Silverlight is monitoring the call stack for these functions and ensuring that only one gets executed.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

As [designed](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2009/05/user-initiated-operations-in.html). ;-)

Comment: +1.  The timeout is the bit that's really relevant to your question - basically, by the time the user clicks OK on the Iso Store Increase Quota dialog, the timeout's likely expired so the SFD.ShowDialog is past the timeout and hence not user-initiated.

This is intentional, so you can't, for instance, spam the user with dozens of Increase Quota prompts until they just say "oh, whatever, sure" as one example.  So it's more about time than number of calls, it just so happens that most of these calls involve UI and thus end up taking long enough for the timeout to kick in.

Comment: @Austin:  I think you'll find the point 4 is also pretty relevant.

Comment: Its a good blog article from the PM on silverlight that I hadn't come across before.  For that reason I'll resist a downvote.  However a simple "read this" answer would normally get a downvote from me.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones. I understand, but I disagree. When necessary I provide very elaborate answers but in this case the blog entry gives a pretty solid answer, so IMHO no need to elaborate further ;-)

Comment: There are many others that would agree with you.  As a long time user I liked the idea that SO actually had the answers, rather than be a launch pad for links to answers.  Time unfortunately has inevitably impacted on the quality of answers.  I tend to compromise and find acceptable some very brief synposis of what is found on the end of the provided link.  This should help find that same content should the link break in the future.  However a "click this" only "answer" is still quite unacceptable in my opinion.